# Como Ligar/Desligar wi-fi no Android?

Tags: android

Como eu ligo e desligo o Wifi no Android? Gostaria de ligar o sinal toda vez que a pessoa abrir o aplicativo, e desligá-lo no momento em que fechar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a classe [`WifiManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) para isso, em particular a função [`setWifiEnabled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#setWifiEnabled%28boolean%29).
Exemplo (dentro de uma activity):

```java
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)
wifi.setWifiEnabled(true); // Liga o WiFi
if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
    // WiFi está ligado
}
```

Note que você precisará acrescentar algumas permissões:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

No seu caso em particular, sugiro não desligar o WiFi ao sair do app se este já estava ligado quando o app foi aberto. Em outras palavras: só desligue se foi você mesmo quem ligou.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou aqui.